# PHP: precision in mathematical operations

Tags: php, rounding, pow

i've a question on PHP and mathematical operations.

**why 9000.05 - 9000 return 0.049999999999272 and not 0.05 ???**

please look that example

```
function calculate ( $financed, $months, $rate){
    $installment = 782.90;  
    $rate= $rate / 100;
    $delta = 0;

    $OUT = $financed;
    $IN  = 0;

    for ($t = 1; $t <= $months; $t++){
        echo "installment $t \n";
        $installment_act =  $installment / pow((1 + ($rate / 12)), $t);
        $installment_act = round($installment_act, 2);
        echo "installment actualized $installment_act \n\n";
        $IN += $installment_act;
        echo "\t\t\t\t $IN\n";
    }
    echo "\n IN ($IN) - OUT ($OUT) = ";
    $delta = $IN - $OUT;
    echo "delta = $delta\n  ";
}

calculate(9000, 12, 8);

//RESULT

installment 1 
installment actualized 777.72 

                 777.72
installment 2 
installment actualized 772.56 

                 1550.28
installment 3 
installment actualized 767.45 

                 2317.73
installment 4 
installment actualized 762.37 

                 3080.1
installment 5 
installment actualized 757.32 

                 3837.42
installment 6 
installment actualized 752.3 

                 4589.72
installment 7 
installment actualized 747.32 

                 5337.04
installment 8 
installment actualized 742.37 

                 6079.41
installment 9 
installment actualized 737.45 

                 6816.86
installment 10 
installment actualized 732.57 

                 7549.43
installment 11 
installment actualized 727.72 

                 8277.15
installment 12 
installment actualized 722.9 

                 9000.05

IN (9000.05) - OUT (9000) = delta = 0.049999999999272
```

**as you see $IN - $OUT return a wrong result, why? and how could i fix it?**

thanks advance for any suggestion
Michele

Comment: most fractional decimal numbers can **NOT** be represented exactly in floating point format. Think of fractional numbers in the same way as the old "We are Pentium of borg, precision is futile. prepare to be approximated" gag line went.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/floating_point#accuracy_problems - applies to almost every programming language known to man

Comment: Use http://php.net/bcmath. Another way to handle money is to use a [Money object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html)

Comment: ***http://php.net/float - do you see the big warning on that page?*** (common mistake)

Comment: A way to handle currency amount with upto two digit decimal place is to multiply all numbers to 100 and play with them as integers. Finally to print, divide by 100 or deliberately put a decimal before last two digits.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar good point, maybe convert it into an answer even

Comment: @Gordon i've tried to use bcmath, only one dubt:
with bcdiv with precision 4 i have this result: 727.7190 but if i use bcdiv with scale precision 2 i have 727.71... is't right to have 727.72 ?

Comment: @ShashwatKumar thank i've think about that solution, now i'm looking for see if exist a 'better way' to solve this problem